# UiAutomator2 server because the instrumentation process is not running python appium error

Tags: python, android, adb

i am trying to automate an app with appium but after the first click i get an error:

````
Stacktrace:
UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: 'POST /element' cannot be proxied to UiAutomator2 server because the instrumentation process is not running (probably crashed). Check the server log and/or the logcat output for more details
    at UIA2Proxy.command (C:\Program Files\Appium Server GUI\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\jsonwp-proxy\proxy.js:274:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)```

Here is my appium server logs:
https://s7.dosya.tc/server21/tede1g/appiumlogs.txt.html
````

Comment: Please do not use external links for providing additional data. Include the relevant parts into your question. Based on the time stamps you should be able to identify the error on server side.

Comment: To check the version of appium that you used and to check the devices that you used.

may i know the specification apps version that you used in you project? thanks